# find other sums similarly under sum

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

In the under sum there exists all number 1,...,9. Similarly write at least 10 sums other.
$$659+214=873.$$
For example we can write $259+614=873$ or $619+254=873$ or $596+142=738$.

Do there exists a method for find these sums?

Do we can find all these sums?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if there is a formula, but I've found $546+381=927$. With trivial permutations of this one (ex : $346+581=927$) and of the 2 others you have, you can make 11 others.

Comment: $596 + 142=738$

Comment: If only $3$ digit numbers were allowed, then it is not hard to do a brute force search on all $1000 \times 1000 = 10^6$ possible combinations.

Comment: There are $168$ Unique solutions, Unique here means $a+b$ & $b+a$ is counted once only.

Comment: @DigitalBrain: How? Please explain more

Comment: @A.G Brute Forcing, takes a fraction of second